# Why is ASP.NET forms authentication setting cookies on a static image request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, forms-authentication, reverse-proxy

I have an ASP.NET (MVC) website that is serving static content (images) as well as dynamic content from the same domain. The site uses forms auth, and has a login controller. There have been some very strange / irregular issues with people finding themselves logged in or out at random intervals, and we've tracked it down to an issue with a reverse proxy caching an image file that has a set-cookie response header that sets the auth cookie. Once this is cached, everyone then gets the same auth cookie, which leads to some very weird outcomes.

My question is - how on earth would an image get a set-cookie header in the first place? What is the ASP.NET forms authentication module doing to cause this - surely it sets the cookie on the main HTML content response. I get that the auth cookie is then sent with all subsequent requests to the domain, but I cannot figure out how the cookie is set in the first place.

(BTW this issue may also be the culprit in at least two existing large ecommerce sites that are suffering from similar problems, with no solution, so it would be a good one to solve).

The response is shown below (taken from fiddler).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400,max-age=86400
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Thu, 04 Nov 2010 16:00:52 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0528474397ccb1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: my-auth-cookie=6BC25F1EF71989466A48C0120E7739E; path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Wed, 17 Nov 2010 17:15:08 GMT
Content-Length: 15790
```

Update: additional info - we are using IIS 7.5 on Win2008 R2, 64bit, and the app is running under an app pool that is using the integrated pipeline / .net 4.

Update 2: I am not looking for a solution to the problem, we have one already. I am looking for an answer to the question, which is why it happened in the first place? Please don't answer telling me about subdomains or how cookies work!

Update 3: adding in the request:

```
GET https://www.example.com/sprite.png HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: my-auth-cookie=6BC25F1EF71989466A48C0120E7739E;
```

Comment: +1, very interesting question. @Hugo, were you able to reproduce this behavior or is it random?

Comment: @Hugo, are you enforcing SSL on your site because I notice that this cookie is set without the `secure` flag?

Comment: Darin, yes we are enforcing SSL - the entire site is running under SSL, although the termination point is the reverse proxy(IIS with ARR installed) not the web servers themselves. The solution to the problem is to serve the images of a different subdomain/site, but as you rightly point out below that doesn't answer the question, which is how / why it happened in the first place.

Comment: we're not sure whether it's repeatable, it was a couple of eagle-eyed devs who spotted the anomaly in a fiddler trace.

Comment: @Hugo, could you try decrypting the authentication ticket from this cookie and see whether it corresponds to some real user that has experienced problems? Also is this a static .png file or is it dynamically generated? Do you have the request headers as well?

Comment: It does correspond to a real user, and yes, they have had problems. I can't confirm the exact trajectory of the cookie - i.e. whether the same value was set for two different users - it's a very hard bug to reproduce.

Comment: What is your forms authentication settings? I tried reproducing it with playing with the `slidingExpiration` and `timeout` attributes. And a response from a static file did add a set-cookie header when forms authentication needed to re-set the cookie expire date. However, that set-cookie header also included an `expires` directive, which is different from your situation.

Comment: Interesting - I'll look into that. It does make some sort of crazy sense that IIS would decide to reset the expiry on a static content file - dangers of using an integrated pipeline approach - we really don't want static files going through the ASP.NET lifecycle. Anyway, in the meantime we will be logging all responses with a set-cookie directive to see how often it occurs on static files.

Comment: Direct from MSDN (http://hrb.fm/bsGes3): "Sliding expiration resets the expiration time for a valid authentication cookie if a request is made and more than half of the timeout interval has elapsed." The killer question here is whether this applies to a cookie received on a request for a static resource (which undergoes no other processing) and I would assume that the answer is yes given the nature of the integrated pipeline. Next question is then whether it's possible to disable the FormsAuth module for non-ASP.NET resources.

Comment: The cookie does not loot like the standard Asp.Net one. Are you creating a custom cookie or did you rename it for some reason?

Comment: IIS7+ Has the ability (as you no doubt know) to route static content and Forms Authentication is apparently managed code part of the run time itself. So it would therefore be logical to assume that in Integrated Pipeline mode its simply being checked/run if its enabled. Do you have this set in the web.config? <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

Comment: I didn't know about the web.config setting, no - I'll pass that on, thanks.

Comment: çağdaş - since the sliding expiration seems to be the answer to the actual question (why does it happen), I'd like to mark your comment as the answer, but can't as it's just a comment. If you copy it into an answer I'll mark this as closed?

Comment: rboarman - a.) yes we are renaming it, and b.) I've hacked the actual header to make it easier to read - the real cookie value is a guid, which does't fit on one line ;-)

Comment: Are/were you maybe running on IIS6 - one of the 'hacks' to get routing to work on IIS6 is to add global wildcard so that all resources get handled by the asp.net runtime - wondering if this could be causing the auth cookie issue?

Comment: Nope - IIS7. The issue is the sliding expiration described above. It seems unbelievably naive, but there you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this myself to close out the question and prevent further updates.

The root cause of the behaviour that I was seeing was due to the integrated pipeline setting cookies on static files (css, images, js) - see the comment thread for further details.

It was solved when we moved static content to a different host in the production / staging environment.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this isn't actually a .NET problem per-se, and the key to your issues is actually the Reverse Proxy.

When serving static content from a forms-auth'ed path, the cookies associated with your connection will get sent along with it. 
So, if you're signed in as user X, session 1 and get image foo.png, your reverse proxy is seeing the PNG file come across with headers indicating it can be cached.

The next time that file is being requested, the reverse proxy is serving the file directly, along with the cookie it had associated with that file when it last got it.

As an experiment, I suggest setting the reverse-proxy to turn off it's caching functionality and see if the problem persists.

If you do need the reverse proxy to be doing caching of content - then I'd suggest then looking to see if the proxy can be told to ignore cookies for cached files, or moving files to another cookieless/auth-less domain.

Comment: Will, you are quite correct, this is the problem, which we've already solved in production. This was more a question to the community about why it happened in the first place (setting cookies on static content). Tying IIS and ASP.NET together may have sounded like a good idea at the time but it's proving a real pain in production scenarios (I have another open question on serverfault about authentication options).

Comment: Hi Hugo, again - I don't think it's .NET / IIS directly that's the problem. As I mentioned, remove the reverse-proxy from the equation, and if I'm right - the problem goes away. If I'm wrong, then it's something deeper.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bug in IIS to me.  I'm going to write some straw-man code to see if I fully understand what's going and and post the results. I'll also test it on IIS 7 and IIS 7.5 to see if it's different.

It really doesn't seem that one request should get ANY cookies associated with a previous request (we DO NOT have any caching proxies on our site and this is happening to us on our internal network, so my conclusing is that IIS is doing it somewhere).

--Owen

Comment: Well, can't reproduce in a simple straw-man example (web page with a bunch of images; another to set cookie). No way, no how do any of the images have the cookie set from a 2nd machine... FWIW

Answer (score 0):

Because you can use Forms Authentication to secure static content.

Comment: And how this answers the question? See the comment I left on @Zain Shaikh answer.

Answer (score -2):

browser by default sends the cookies with each request made on the `same domain`.

the simple solution is to move your images to some other domain, like `youtube` guys have a domain `http://s.ytimg.com/yt/img/watch/` to save all the images.

Comment: Don't you read the question? Don't you see the `Set-Cookie` response header? This is setting a cookie and not the client passing it through the `Cookie` header in the request.