# How to understand a security warning in google chrome for a static resource served by Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, caching, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I inspected our web application with the Audit feature in the Google Chrome developer tools.

First I got a warning, indicating that we are serving our static content none-cacheable: "The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making the cacheable if possible".

To fix this I added this snippet to our web-config

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

as recommended in this blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2009/06/09/are-you-caching-your-images-and-scripts-iis-seo-can-tell-you.aspx

If I now start a new audit in google chrome, I get a new warning:

> The following publicly cacheable resources contain a Set-Cookie
>   header. This security vulnerability can cause cookies to be shared by
>   multiple users.

Can you explain the potential security threat and what is a possible solution in Asp.net?

**[Update]**

After some more research, I guess this could be related to this question:

[Why is ASP.NET forms authentication setting cookies on a static image request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208089/why-is-asp-net-forms-authentication-setting-cookies-on-a-static-image-request)

But I can't put the puzzle together. The situation is not exactly the same, while our application could be configured to use forms authentication, I got the warning while using windows authentication.

Comment: Are you sure the two are event connected?  The security threat is pretty clear, the same cookie could be used by multiple users, this isn't a problem on a single user computer of course.

Comment: @Ramhound At least the chrome tools think there is a connection. If I remove the cache instruction from the webconfig I get another warning instead: The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible:

Comment: You can add 'Cache-Control' header with a value 'private', which indicates the resource can be cached only by a client but not by intermediate machines. This way the same cookie should not be returned to different clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem was really related to forms authentication. After authenticating the user we set a forms authentication coockie. This coockie has no path set, so it will be sent for every request, even for static images.

It looks like I still had the coockie set from a previous debug session even though I was testing windows authentication.

I think the best solution would be to set a path for the coockie to prevent it from being sent for static resources. Unfortunately I can not define a path for all our service requests, because we are using WCF Ria Services and the services have a virtual path created a runtime.

The solution for now is set the coockie only in the browser. The updated entry in the web config is:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" cacheControlCustom="private"/>
</staticContent>
```

The important part is the new cacheControlCustom attribute.

I guess this could still be a security problem, if a browser is shared by more than one user (e.g. in an Internet cafe?), but this is not a valid scenario for our project.