# How to get rid of "Forms authentication failed for the request (...)" exceptions in authenticationless subapp?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a site that uses forms authentication. There are two more subapps alongside the site. Those subapps deliver static files, JSONS for ajax calls etc. Authentication in those subapps is set to "none", yet at least one of those subapps throws this exception every now and then:

> Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket
>   supplied was invalid.

I'm guessing that whenever this exception is thrown user doesn't get the static content or ajax response (it's not like I can easily recreate the situation either). How to make the subapps ignore forms authentication (they don't use it for anything anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208089/why-is-asp-net-forms-authentication-setting-cookies-on-a-static-image-request) question. It's not asking about the same thing, but it seems to be related. From that question I learned that one way to solve my problem would by moving my subapps to a different domain (or subdomain). I can't really use it in my case, but, but someone with this particular problem might find it useful.